# Call a jquery modal box by server side event

Tags: asp.net, jquery

i would like to call a jquery dialog box (so html, css,javascript ) via asp.net Server Side event.
Is it possible ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define the script to run on the client, something like this (change options as needed):

```
var myScript = "$('#myDialog').dialog();";
```

Then in ASP.Net if you're in an UpdatePanel situation:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(myPanel, typeof(UpdatePanel), "showDialog",
                                    myScript, true);
```

Or, if you're in a normal full page situation:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "showDialog",
                                   myScript, true);
```